# Javascript: Take two numbers from an array and divide the array into three subarrays. Find the minimum sum of the two numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

There is an array of N integers. We will take two numbers from the array and split this array into three parts. To be exact, we will take elements at index P and Q. And the subarrays' indices will be [0, P-1], [P+1, Q-1], [Q+1, N-1]. Obviously, 0 < P < Q < N-1, Q-P > 1. We want to find the minimum sum of the two numbers.

For example, there are three ways which we can take two numbers from the array [5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7].

- indices 1 & 3. The sum is 8
- indices 1 & 4. The sum is 5.
- indices 2 & 4. The sum is 7.

So the minimum sum is 5.

I have tried and written the following function to achieve this effect. Obviously it is very slow. But I cannot think of a way to write faster algorithms.

```
const arrayOne = [5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7]
console.log(arrayOne)

const breakChain = (arr) => {
 let lowest = 2000000000
 for (let open = 1; open < arr.length - 3; open ++) {
  for (let close = open + 2; close < arr.length - 1; close ++) {
   const low = arr[open] + arr[close]
   if (low < lowest) {
    lowest = low
   }
  }
 }
 console.log(lowest)
}

breakChain(arrayOne)
```

Comment: This is an homework. Try it yourself

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing or tutorial service. The objective is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried it myself. Obviously it is not the fastest algorithm in the world.

Comment: So it works? What is the specific problem?

Comment: Not that this affects running speed, but you can use `Number.MAX_VALUE` or `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` rather than your hardcoded `2000000000` and is a little more clear in its intent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Algorithm that should work and has a better time complexity compared to yours.

If arr[ ] stores your numbers in some order, then using a good sorting algorithm (you can google it online), store them in ascending order. Let's store them in arr1[ ].

Now, arr1[0] and arr[1] yields the smallest sum if arr1[0] \neq arr[0] \neq arr[n]. Also, arr1[1] \neq arr[i +- 1] and arr[1] \neq arr[0] or arr[n]. Use binary search to check the conditions.

If these conditions don't hold between arr1[0], arr1[1], then check for arr1[1], arr1[2] and so on. Note that it won't go till arr1[n]. At max, it may go half-way through the sorted array till it breaks. And remember to break the loop when you're done.

I hope this serves your purpose!